# How to get rid of this error when trying to run ruby-debug on a ruby script

Tags: ruby, debugging

I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug/blob/master/README) but still have trouble figuring out the problem. Would be great to hear some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

```
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ gem install ruby-debug19
Fetching: archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: ruby_core_source-0.1.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: linecache19-0.5.12.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: ruby-debug19-0.11.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2
Successfully installed ruby_core_source-0.1.5
Successfully installed linecache19-0.5.12
Successfully installed ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25
Successfully installed ruby-debug19-0.11.6
5 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2...
Building YARD (yri) index for archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2...
Installing ri documentation for ruby_core_source-0.1.5...
Building YARD (yri) index for ruby_core_source-0.1.5...
Installing ri documentation for linecache19-0.5.12...
Building YARD (yri) index for linecache19-0.5.12...
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25...
Building YARD (yri) index for ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25...
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug19-0.11.6...
Building YARD (yri) index for ruby-debug19-0.11.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby_core_source-0.1.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for linecache19-0.5.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug19-0.11.6...
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ ruby-debug ex39.rb
ruby-debug: command not found
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ ruby-debug19
ruby-debug19: command not found
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ rdebug ex40.rb
/home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so (LoadError)
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/bin/rdebug:108:in `require_relative'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/bin/rdebug:108:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rdebug:19:in `load'
    from /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rdebug:19:in `<main>'
```

----------Update---------------------------

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling ruby-debug and linecache, and still failed.
Here's the log of what happened:

```
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ gem install linecache
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing linecache:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_make.out
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ gem uninstall linecache
INFO:  gem "linecache" is not installed
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ gem install linecache
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing linecache:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_make.out
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ gem uninstall ruby-debug
INFO:  gem "ruby-debug" is not installed
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ gem install ruby-debug
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/stanley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/stanley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up solving my problem by installing the gem `debugger` instead: http://rubygems.org/gems/debugger

- Add the gem to your Gemfile: `gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]`
- Run bundler: `bundle install`

If you need some guidance on how use the gem follow the video tutorial [Creating a blog in 15 minutes with Rails - Part 2](http://youtu.be/zG_mvp8u4cI). Basically, you need to do two things to interrupt the server rendering a page.

- Add the command `debugger` somewhere in your ruby code. If its a view use `<% debugger %>` instead.
- Start the server with a parameter: `rails server --debugger`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that ruby-debug19 is not 1.9.3 ready - see http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug for similar symptoms to yours and a workaround

Comment: I added more information about what I've tried from the suggestions.